# How to pass values to BitSet Class and create list containing BitSet Values?

Tags: java

- ```
  BitSet bits1 = new BitSet(00101010); 
  System.out.println(bits1);
  ```

Question : Why the output is returning { }.

- ```
  List<BitSet> list = new ArrayList<BitSet>();
  list.add(new BitSet(00010010));
  list.add(new BitSet(10000001));
  list.add(new BitSet(01000001));
  System.out.println(test.orTogether(list));
  ```

Not able to pass values to the method. As the list contains [{ }, { }, { }].

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that the constructor `public BitSet(int)` doesn't take the bits, but the number of bits you want to store. So, the content is still empty...

To set the bits, you can create an extra method:

```
public BitSet createBitSet(String bits)
{
    int len = bits.length();
    BitSet bs = new BitSet(len);
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        bs.set(len - i - 1, bits.charAt(i) == '1');
    }
    return bs;
}
```

And then:

```
list.add(createBitSet("00010011"));
```

(I didn't test the method, so they may be some errors...)

Answer (score 1):

To construct your BitSet objects you probably want to use a method similar to:

```
static BitSet createBitSetFromString( String s ) {
  BitSet ret = new BitSet( s.length );
  for( int i = 0 ; i < s.length() ; i++ ){
    if( s.charAt( i ) == '1' ) {
      ret.set( s.length() - 1 - i ) ;
    }
  }
  return ret ;
}
```

then, instead of

```
BitSet bits1 = new BitSet(00101010);
```

You can do:

```
BitSet bits1 = createBitSetFromString( "00101010" ) ;
```

Comment: You method doesn't work. Bits are right-aligned, so you are creating the bits in reversed order.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple factory method to create a `BitSet` from a binary input String (I copied it from [this previous answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5244761/or-operation-in-javabitset-class/5244938#5244938)):

```
public static BitSet createBitset(final String input){
    final int length = input.length();
    final BitSet bitSet = new BitSet(length);
    for(int i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
        // anything that's not a 1 is a zero, per convention
        bitSet.set(i, input.charAt(i) == '1');
    }
    return bitSet;
}
```

You can also use it with `int` or `long` bit masks by using `toBinaryString()`

```
int someInt = 1234567;
long someLong = 1234567890L;
BitSet bitSetFromInt =
    createBitset(Integer.toBinaryString(someInt));
BitSet bitSetFromLong =
    createBitset(Long.toBinaryString(someLong));
System.out.println(bitSetFromInt);
System.out.println(bitSetFromLong);
```

**Output:**

> {0, 3, 5, 6, 8, 10, 11, 13, 18, 19, 20}
>   {0, 3, 6, 7, 10, 12, 13, 21, 23, 24, 26, 29}

Comment: You method doesn't work. Bits are right-aligned, so you are creating the bits in reversed order.

Answer (score 0):

From the [BitSet documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html):

> BitSet(int nbits) 
>             Creates a bit set whose initial size is large enough to
>   explicitly represent bits with indices
>   in the range 0 through nbits-1.

You need to initialise the BitSet properly (e.g. for `01001`):

```
BitSet bs = new BitSet(5);
bs.set(0, true);
bs.set(3, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

The BitSet constructor takes an int which is the initial size, not a binary number.  You need to set the bits like this:

```
bitset.set(2);
bitset.set(4);
bitset.set(6);
```